# Exception on deserialization of JSON object with string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

#### Problem:

I'm in need of deserialization a JSON object. 
However, it appears that an array of strings in the object causes an exception and i can't figure out why.

I've used tools such as [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to ensure that my JSON is in the correct format and that the class I deserialize to is correct. In both cases the tools give an okay and shows no error. Yet I still get the exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### JSON:

```
{
"ID":123,
"Content":[ "{\"NewName\":\"asd\",\"Type\":\"2\"}]}" ],
"Notes":[""],
"Type":2,
"Subjects":"asd",
"Classes":"1",
"Name":"fdsgfd",
"Assign_Content":[
"[{\"Type\":\"text\",\"Text\":\"dfgfgs\"]"
],
"Creator":"example@example.com",
"isActive":"False",
"Editor":"example@example.com",
"CreatedDate":"2017-08-22T00:00:00",
"LastModifiedDate":"2017-08-22T00:00:00"
}
```

#### Deserialize:

`var task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(JSON);`

#### Class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Content { get; set; }
    public List<string> Notes { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Subjects { get; set; }
    public string Classes { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Assign_Content { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public string isActive { get; set; }
    public string Editor { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

#### Exception:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: After parsing a value an unexpected character
>   was encountered: N. Path 'Content[0]', line 1, position 23.

#### Edit

Thanks to kblok i did this:

```
JSON = "{\"ID\":123,\"Content\":[\"{\"NewName\":\"fdsgfd\",\"Type\":\"2\"}\"],\"Notes\":[\"\"],\"Type\":2,\"Subjects\":\"Tysk\",\"Classes\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"fdsgfd\",\"Assign_Content\":[\"[{\"Type\":\"text\",\"Text\":\"dfgfgs\"}]\"],\"Creator\":\"example@example.com\",\"isActive\":\"False\",\"Editor\":\"example@example.com\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2017-08-22T00:00:00\",\"LastModifiedDate\":\"2017-08-22T00:00:00\"}";
to
JSON= "{\"ID\":123,\"Content\":[\"{\\\"NewName\\\":\\\"fdsgfd\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"2\\\"}\"],\"Notes\":[\"\"],\"Type\":2,\"Subjects\":\"Tysk\",\"Classes\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"fdsgfd\",\"Assign_Content\":[\"[{\\\"Type\\\":\\\"text\\\",\\\"Text\\\":\\\"dfgfgs\\\"}]\"],\"Creator\":\"example@example.com\",\"isActive\":\"False\",\"Editor\":\"example@example.com\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2017-08-22T00:00:00\",\"LastModifiedDate\":\"2017-08-22T00:00:00\"}";
```

and it now works!

Comment: I would not have thought that would parse as valid json. You have an extraneous `]}` in `Content` and deserialization will choke on it.

Comment: @Crowcoder Good eye. I tried again after removing the ]}. Yet the error still occurred. Content is a array of strings. These strings are JSON. I guess the deserializer doesn't see it as a string and it breaks.

Comment: That structure will try to deserialize as a list/array of object with two properties: `NewName` and `Type`, not a list of strings. I think you should run Json2CSharp again after removing the extra brackets.

Comment: Can you show how *exactly* is the 'JSON' string composed (code-wise)?

Comment: @Crowcoder Do you know of a way to force it to see `Content` as a string?

Comment: @Hiws, not without some trial and error. Maybe doubling up the brackets: `{{`...`}}` would force it to treat it as a string instead of an object? Are you sure you want to though? That typically wouldn't be very useful as a string. `Assign_Content` will have similar issues.

Comment: I saved that json in a file, loaded it with a TextReader and it worked

Comment: @Crowcoder The reason for this, is that the string is being stored in a database, so you can pull from the database and parse the content to get an array, based on the previous devs comments. Sadly i can't change this format to make it so it has it's own table, so i'm stuck with this.
I might just have to do a lot of trail and error or change up the way i recieve the JSON. (Split it out and merge later)

Comment: @kblok, by "it worked" do you mean the `Content` field read the data as an array of strings verbatim into the `RootObject` class? Maybe you can share your code.

Comment: @kblok If that's the case. Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: How are you loading that json?

Comment: Yes I confirm @kblok, your json is valid and I am also able to load it to a `RootObject` .

Comment: @kblok Currently as seen in the edit at the bottom. And as CrowCoder asked, it would be nice if you could share the code.

Comment: @Hiws, they are correct, read from a file your code works so forget most everything I said.

Comment: @Crowcoder kblok found the solution. Had to escape the escape in the strings inside the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of this string:

```
\"Content\":[\"{\"NewName\":\"fdsgfd\",\"Type\":\"2\"}\"]
```

is:

```
"Content":["{"NewName":"fdsgfd","Type":"2"}"]
```

And that, as you can see, is an invalid JSON. So you need to escape the backslash, in order to get a valid JSON. Instead of this:

```
\"{\"NewName\":\"fdsgfd\",\"Type\":\"2\"}\"
```

It should be:

```
\"{\\\"NewName\\\":\\\"fdsgfd\\\",\\\"Type\\\":\\\"2\\\"}\"
```